# which redis datatype is suitable for storing users?

Tags: ruby, security, authentication, encryption, redis

I am building an authentication system in ruby, and using redis for storing users' access data. I like to know which of [redis datatypes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) is more suitable to use?

Comment: i have been away from stackoverflow for a while thts why

Answer (score 1):

None of them. Redis is supposed to be used in a trusted environment, its own authentication mechanism is basic, and there is no access right or ACL associated to data. It is quite weak to store security sensitive data.

Now, if you really need to do it, you can either serialize the properties of your users and store each user in a single string, or use one hash object per user to store the properties separately.

For instance:

```
SET user:1 {"lastname":"Smith","firstname":"John","passwd":"38E56712AB15"}
or
HMSET user:1 lastname Smith firstname John passwd 38E56712AB15
```

The first solution is more optimal if you access the users systematically in a global way (retrieving/updating all the properties in one shot).

With the second solution, it is a bit easier to encrypt only one part of the data, and to support partial update/retrieval. Of course encryption must be done on client side.

Comment: With a structure like that, how do you go about looking up some specific user, say "John Smith", when he's trying to log in?

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced Redis is less safe than any RDBMS you'd typically hook up to your web app. It's all just a matter of coming up with an architecture appropriate for the security you need.

Comment: With Redis, you need to anticipate all possible access paths to the data. If you require to search by lastname+firtname, you can add a hash object to index these fields. HMSET name_index Smith/John 1

Comment: Any RDBMS is way more secure than Redis (with roles, access rights, different administration levels, etc ...).

Comment: Adding a separate hash for user lookup would work, yes. Are you sure it's a better option than just using the login as part of the key, though?

Comment: It depends on your data model. Having numerical keys can help if you need to keep set of users, or index some other properties of the users. Redis makes use of an optimized memory representation in that case, that you will not be able to benefit from if your keys are just strings.

Comment: Wow, that's a closed-minded answer.  Security is what you make of it.